# Node.js communicate with external API with oauth2, auth without login/client side UI

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I am trying to create a very small node server that can do a few calls to another external API that uses oAuth2.

I'm going to store the credentials to login into the external API on the server so I can do all the steps to get the access tokens and bearer tokens without any user/client-side login/ui.

The server is just acting as a middleware/bridge to the external API, so that not all of the API is exposed.

Goal is to just have a website that GET call to nodeServer without any authorization and then the nodeServer does a request to external API with authentication and returns data to nodeServer and then website. I don't want to any user login.

Steps I need to do with external API to get authentication:

1. **Get Auth Code** https:// auth.bullhornstaffing.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=client_id}&action=login&username=XXX&password=XXX
2. **Get Access Token** 
   https:// auth.bullhornstaffing.com/oauth/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code={auth_code}&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}
3. **Get Bearer Token and RestURL** https:// rest.bullhornstaffing.com/rest-services/login?version=*&access_token={access_token}

I have tried to using Simple-oAuth2 and Passport but I can't get them to work without needing a client login ui and redirect. Also the external API doesn't like localhost/127.0.0.1 redirects.